# Adding Name to Date Range Search. MS Access VBA

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

So I am making a defects database in MS Access for work and I am working on a search form to find a specific employees defects between specific dates. I already have the date range search working with a button, but I haven't figured out how to add my EmployeeNameBox into the filter results. This is what I have.

```
Private Sub Searchbtn_Click()
    Me.Filter = "[DayMonthYear] BETWEEN #" & Me.Date1Filt & "# AND #" & Me.Date2Filt & "#"
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Works great for the date range I want, but I need to add in the employee name as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your `EmployeeNameBox` will always be populated when searching, you just need to add it to your filter. I've found it's easier to store your filter in a variable, then assign it to `Me.Filter` at the end. So something like:

```
Private Sub Searchbtn_Click()
    Dim sFilter as String

    sFilter = _
            "[DayMonthYear] BETWEEN " & _
                "#" & Me.Date1Filt & "# AND " & _
                "#" & Me.Date2Filt & "# " & _
            " AND [EmployeeName] = """ & Me.EmployeeNameBox & """"

    Me.Filter = sFilter
    Me.FilterOn = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The only problem I'm having is it pops up a message box asking for the employee name now. The employee name box is a dropdown list of names, maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to adjust the last part of `sFilter` to reflect the actual employee field name. Also, if the employee field is a number rather than text, you'll need to adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Awesome thank you so much. It was my fault actually. I misspelled the field name, it was right the first time. :)